# Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException Drawable com.companyname.mySchool:drawable/splash_screen with resource ID #0x7f02012c

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Visual Studio for Android app, although my build is successful, 
Application throws an exception, below attached screenshot of my exception

although i searched for solution but unable to find relevant one.

[image]

SplashActivity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace MySchool.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MySchool", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme =         "@style/Theme.splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Task startup = new Task(StartUp);
            startup.Start();
        }

        async void StartUp()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context,     typeof(MainActivity)));
            }

    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace MySchool.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "myschools", Theme = "@style/MainTheme",     ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

Splash_Screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
      <padding android:left="0dip"
               android:top="0dip"
               android:right="0dip"
               android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <drawable  android:src="@drawable/myschool"
               android:gravity="center" >
    </drawable>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Actually I tried to make my SplashActivity the mainlauncher using my splash_screen icon to appear when my app is going live, below are the code snippets and also at the top exception screenshot.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please insert the actual code, just rename your blurred out words.

Comment: Actually to be more precise i have created a new activity and made it as mainlauncher = true, edited my post please go through

Comment: Check whether Splash_Screen.xml is present in your drawable folder if it is not move it there

Comment: @G.hakim its there in drawable folder, but still getting this exception, unable to figure out why its coming.

Comment: Well, do one thing delete the ResourceDesigner.cs file under the Resources folder delete the bin and obj folders and Clean build the app once and try it then

Comment: @G.hakim did what you mention, build is failing with three errors,
`CS0103  C# The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context`
this is referencing to my splash & main activity where I have  `Resource.Layout.Tabbar;`

Comment: you did not include the resource designer back kindly do it and rebuild and revert incase of problems

Comment: @G.hakim it worked thank you so much for your patience

Comment: How did it work exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Start off, I don't see your Splash Activity's layout being set in `OnCreate()`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splash_Screen); //This Line is needed
}
```

This is what the `Splash_Screen.axml` looks like inside in the folder `Resources\layout\Splash_Screen.axml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/splash_background"
      android:scaleType="fitXY" />
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:paddingBottom="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBottomText"
        android:text="Hello and welcome to stackoverflow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

### **Edit**

Try this code in your `SplashActivity.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace MySchool.Droid
{
    [Activity(MainLauncher = true, Label = "MySchool", Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splash);

            new Handler().PostDelayed(() =>
            {
                StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)));
                Finish();
            }, 2500);
        }
    }
}
```

Then make sure you add the following File `Splash.axml` inside the `Resources` Folder, Inside the `layout` folder `MySchool.Droid\Resources\layout\Splash.axml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBottomText"
        android:text="Hello and welcome to stackoverflow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You should be able to see the Splash screen then for 2.5 seconds.

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for the quick answer but i did try adding that line but it throws an error  'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'splash_screen'

Comment: @kishore Compare your Resource file with mine and see that yours is not an Android layout file but rather a drawable

Comment: yup i have added the same to my layout as well but the old exception still remains, and by the way i dont want this splash layout to appear as launcher i just want to show my logo as splash screen for some time while my background stuff loads as I launch my application. so this was my intention. hope you got my problem.

Comment: @kishore okay so you have added a new activity in Android, this activity must have it's own layout file inside the correct folder ie. `MyProj.Droid\Resources\Layout\Splash.axml`. This is then set in `OnCreate` of the Activity with the line `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splash);`, after you have added code in `OnResume` to "Timeout" or delay the splash screen Asynchronously whilst loading the other stuff, then you start your `MainActivity` with Intent which in turn will start the Xamarin Forms project

Comment: i'm still struck with the same exception, build is successful but exception while running the app, it seems like the exception is coming from here, if u see in my SplashActivity i have a  `Theme = "@style/Theme.splash"` in which im using my a custom theme code is like below

` <style name="Theme.splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>`

Comment: @kishore In that case, create a small png in paint, save it as `splash_screen.png` and put it in the `MySchool.Droid\Resources\drawables\` folder. Clean (delete Bin+Obj folder) and Rebuild